# MySQL concurrency, how does it work and do I need to handle it in my application

Tags: mysql

I am currently running a MySQL database. All of my tables are using the Table Engine InnoDB.

Everyone who logs into my application can view records and I am worried that at some point two users might update or insert a record at the same time. Does MySQL handle this type of concurrency issue gracefully, or is this something that I am going to have to program into my code?

If I do have to program it into my code how do you go about handling a concurrency case like this?

Comment: You don't need to care about these. Modern day's Databases are smart enough in concurrency control :)

Comment: thats what I figured I just wanted to double check

Comment: Apart from wrapping queries in transactions, you only need to handle deadlocks, which don't occur very often.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

SQL statements are atomic. That is, if you execute something like this:

```
UPDATE Cars SET Sold = Sold + 1
```

Nobody can change the `Sold` variable during this statement. It is always incremented by 1, even if somebody else is executing the same statement concurrently.

The problem occurs if you have statements that depend on each other:

```
a = SELECT Sold FROM Cars;
UPDATE Cars SET Sold = a + 1;
```

Between these queries, another user can change the table Cars and update Sold. To prevent this, wrap it in a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
a = SELECT Sold FROM Cars;
UPDATE Cars SET Sold = a + 1;
COMMIT;
```

Transactions are supported by InnoDB, but not by MyISAM.

Comment: Even in a transaction there's no guarantee. MySQL by default, does row-level locking/table-locking only for write operations, even in transactions.
To make **a** have a correct value, it's necessary to put *FOR UPDATE* in SELECT, or to specify a higher *isolation level* on TRANSACTION as *SERIALIZABLE*. **More info:** [Internal locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html),
[Isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html),
[Locking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: is this statement true?  
_Nobody can change the Sold variable during this statement. It is always incremented by 1, even if somebody else is executing the same statement concurrently_

Comment: @nulll Yes, it's true, the it's A in [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), Atomicity.

Comment: What about the following concurrent queries? UPDATE jobs SET assigned_to = 1 WHERE assigned IS NULL LIMIT 1; UPDATE jobs SET assigned = 2 WHERE ts IS NULL AND assigned_to IS NULL LIMIT 1; They will always "assign" two rows? Or I can have a situation where only one row is assigned (to 1 or 2). Trying to make forever running concurrent scripts pulling jobs to do with SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE assigned = <script_id> (1 or 2), exit if empty, obviously without premature terminating scripts if there are jobs to do.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you have this query

```
BEGIN;
a = SELECT Sold FROM Cars where id = 1;
UPDATE Cars SET Sold = a + 1 where id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Between the select statement and update statement, anyone can change the sold value, so your query must be:

```
BEGIN;
a = SELECT Sold FROM Cars where id = 1 for update;
UPDATE Cars SET Sold = a + 1 where id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

the `for update` will lock the row with `id = 1` from cars table, so other transaction that access the cars table with `id = 1` will temporarily freeze until the current transaction finish.