# Can multiple users insert into a server database simultaneously?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database on my server, and a Windows WPF application from which my clients will be inserting and deleting rows corresponding to their data. There may be hundreds of users working on the application at the same time, and they will be inserting or deleting rows in the db.

My question is whether or not all the database execution can go successfully or should I adapt some other alternative?

PS: There won't be any clash on rows while insertion/deletion by users as a user will be able to add/remove his/her corresponding data only.

Comment: It depends on how did you implement your application

Comment: Of course.  That's one of the reasons you use a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is whether or not all the database execution can go successfully ...

Yes, like most other relational database systems, MySQL supports concurrent inserts, updates and deletes so this shouldn't be an issue provided that the operations don't conflict with each other.

If they do, you need to find a way to manage concurrency.

[MySQL concurrency, how does it work and do I need to handle it in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828490/mysql-concurrency-how-does-it-work-and-do-i-need-to-handle-it-in-my-application)